# Setting dynamic css-background image in wordpress post [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, background-image, concatenation

I have a site based on wordpress and I want to change the header image for every single post. As every post has its own 'id', I want to make a jquery function which would read the post 'id' (for example id="post-8") and would set a background image named the same way, so I just have to make a new image and upload it everytime I write a new post, and no css changes would be needed.

I have very bare idea of jquery, but my bro's help I got the following code:

```
var txt1 = "post-";
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
        var elementId = txt1.concat(i);
        var postimg1 = "url(../images/";
        var postimg2 = ".jpg)";
        var postimgfull = postimg1 + elementId + postimg2;
        var element =  $("#" + elementId);
        if (element != null) {
            $(".posthead").css('background-image', postimgfull);
        }else {
            break;
        }
```

But using that I don't get the image named "post-8.jpg", what I get is an image named "post-999.jpg".

Can you help me here?

Thankyou mates!

Comment: seems more logical to do this in php. at least i would. You can put php in any template file, like header.php, read the url requested and so on. easy.

Comment: Definitely.  It might make even more sense to have the header image be pulled from the featured image so you can do everything right when you're creating a post.

Comment: Well, I'm placing that in a php page, but I agree, it'd be better to do it in php. But I don't really know anything about php... (I mean less than js). If you can help here, that'd be awesome, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess everything goes fine in your code except there should be

`element.css('background-image', postimgfull);`

in stead of

`$(".posthead").css('background-image', postimgfull);`

and it should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks mate! It was that. It was my first option but I didn't try cause I wanted another element to take the css action but obviously the "element" thing was absolutely necessary here: `$(element).find('.posthead').css('background-image', postimgfull);`